# create a list in python with random numbers, size depends on user

Tags: python-3.x

In Python, i would like to create a list called MyList with random numbers from range 0 to 100(included). i got that which is:

```
import random

MyList=[]
for i in range(10):
    MyList.append(random.randint(1,101))
MyList
```

The above will create 10 pseudo-numbers in the range 1-100. I would like to ask user "Please tell me how many numbers to present: "
Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: Use `input` to get the number, save it in a variable, then pass that variable to `range`.  `x = int(input('Please tell me how many numbers to present: ')); for i in range(x):`

Comment: any ideas why it returns errors when i input your code? it comes with the following error: TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'range'. The code i have is: import random
range.x = int(input('Please tell me how many numbers to present: '));

MyList=[]
for i in range(x):
    MyList.append(random.randint(1,101))
MyList

Comment: The code snippet I posted starts with `x=`.  The `range` is the last word in the previous sentence